# How to prevent the removal of selected options from the dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

It is good, if there will be an opportunity to hang a class on these elements in the list.

```js
$(function(){
  $('select').selectize({
    plugins: ['restore_on_backspace', 'remove_button']
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) has a callback function **onOptionRemove(value)** that deletes these items. But I did not find the opposite effect.
Why this possibility is not out of the box, a simple parameter is true / false =))
I looked through all the examples in the documentation and found no solution. I ask for your help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option: it's `hideSelected`. I've edited your code to set `hideSelected` to false. Is that what you're looking for?

```js
$(function(){
  $('select').selectize({
    hideSelected: false,
    plugins: ['restore_on_backspace', 'remove_button']
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes. I read the documentation but did not notice this option. I am a loser :D 
Difficult night. Thank you.